# Could not locate update bundle - Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

*Electron-Builder Version: 22.14.2*

*Node Version: 16.14.2*

*Electron Version: 13.1.9*

*Electron Type (current, beta, nightly): current*

*Target: MacOS, but i need WML*

> [Error: Could not locate update bundle for com.github.Electron within
> file:///Users/lucas/Library/Caches/com.github.Electron.ShipIt/update.erv01nk/]
> { code: 2, domain: 'SQRLUpdaterErrorDomain' } Error: Error: Could not
> locate update bundle for com.github.Electron within
> file:///Users/lucas/Library/Caches/com.github.Electron.ShipIt/update.erv01nk/

When I try to do the update, it throws this error right after finishing the download and calling autoUpdater.quitAndInstall()